# JSX element type '...' does not have any construct or call signatures

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-typescript

I've got a newbie question about typescipting react namespace components

so i have a MyButton component

```
type MyButtonProps{
 face?: string
}

usage:
<MyButton face="smile">Smiling</MyButton>
```

and i want to use this MyButton component in Parent component but namespace it to Parent.Child

```
type ParentComponent<T = {}> = React.FC<T> & {
  Child?: React.FC<MyButtonProps>;
};

type ParentProps = {
 color: string;
}

const Parent: ParentComponent<ParentProps> = (props)=>{ ... };
Parent.Child = MyButton;

usage:
<Parent>
   <Parent.Child face="lol">Hello World!</Parent.Child>
</Parent>
```

But i keep getting this typescript error

**JSX element type 'Parent.Child' does not have any construct or call signatures. ts(2604)**

and not sure how to resolve this

Can someone shed some light. Thank you in advanced...

Comment: What is `</Parent/Child>`? Shouldn't it be `</Parent.Child>`?

Comment: fixed thanks....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because Child is optional. You either want to make Child required (`Child?:` -> `Child:`) or check to see if it's declared before using it (if it won't always be defined):

```
 {Parent.Child && <Parent.Child face="lol">Hello World!</Parent.Child>}
```

Comment: thank you so much!! i was it was more complicated to fix than that!! :D ... thanks again!